# How to paste headings into a list without having the list's initial headings' numbering shifted

Tags: vba, ms-word

In my testing, copying and pasting text with headings that aren't part of a numbered list into another word file that does have a numbered list causes word to automatically integrate the pasted headings as new "elements" of the list. As such, it creates additional numbering (in addition to the numbering it might've had before) for each of those headings and shifts the numbering of the subsequent initial headings.

Copied Text:
[image: To be Copied Text]
Before Paste:
[image: Text before paste]
After Paste:
[image: After paste]
Is there a way not to have those initial headings shifted while still maintaining this list structure?

I did think of the method:
`ConvertNumbersToText`

That would prevent word from automatically numbering everything for me that comes near that list. But is there another solution? I would rather not use it because I do not know how to turn back on "automatic numbering".

**[Edit 1]:**
Another solution that worked was pasting and formatting with the recovery type below:
`wdFormatOriginalFormatting`

However, this fix would fail whenever I would be pasting headings that have lists in it. Instead, when copying headings with lists inside of their bodies, pasting normally (`Selection.Paste`) doesn't shift the numbering or create any new numbering for the pasted lists.

Comment: It's not clear how this is a programming question, although it is tagged [vba], but the descriptive text and the reason for the behavior is more "end-user". Two people have already voted to close it for that reason. If it is programming, then it needs to include some code (attempt) or something that makes that clear to stop the CVs and keep it from being "too broad".

Comment: The reason behind what you're seeing is that these headings are (almost certainly) all formatted with Word's built-in Heading styles. When you copy/paste (or use `Range.FormattedText`) to transfer between documents the default behavior is to apply the same style formatting to all text formatted with the same style name. This includes the numbering assigned to the Heading styles in the target document, in your case.

Comment: Your only way around this would start with applying a different style to the headings coming in from the other document.

Comment: As I've added in the question, `Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)` seems to be a solution but it's only applicable to headings without lists in their bodies. Programatically, how would I go about applying different styles while preserving the same formatting (don't need the full code, just a lead)?

Comment: Difficult to explain... See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to copy a style which could then be modified. But it is possible to create a new style that bases on another, then modify the new one to be slightly different (i.e. remove the numbering).

The following code snippet

1. declares and instantiates two `Style` objects: one for the Heading 1 style, the other a new style.
2. The `BaseStyle` property for the new style is then set to the Heading 1 style, meaning it picks up all of the base style's properties.
3. Then it is unlinked from the numbering by setting its `ListTemplate` to `Nothing`

When I copy/paste this to a document where Heading 1 is numbered this text is not numbered, but otherwise looks the same. It can also be picked up in a TOC (a TOC can also be modified to *not* pick it up, if that's the desired behavior).

```
Sub CopyStyleAndUnlinkNumbering()
    Dim sH1 As Word.style
    Dim sH1Copy As Word.style

    Set sH1 = ActiveDocument.styles(WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1)
    Set sH1Copy = ActiveDocument.styles.Add("Heading 1 Copy", Word.WdStyleType.wdStyleTypeParagraph)
    sH1Copy.BaseStyle = sH1
    sH1Copy.LinkToListTemplate ListTemplate:=Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, I'll then be applying this to all the headings that are found within a document before copying them.